# Derived Class Constructor from an Abstract Class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a problem with Derived Class from an Abstract Class
Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
  int a,b;
public:
  A(): a(0), b(0) {}
  A(int na,int nb): a(na), b(nb) {}
  virtual void print() = 0; // Reason to be an abstract class
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  B(int a, int b)  {A(a,b);}
  void print()
  {
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
  }
};

int main(){

  B clase(3,2);
  clase.print();
  return 0;
}
```

The above code give me an error like this:

```
lab1.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B(int, int)’:
lab1.cpp:20:10: error: invalid cast to abstract class type ‘A’
     A(a,b);
          ^
lab1.cpp:5:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘A’:
 class A
       ^
lab1.cpp:12:16: note:   virtual void A::print()
   virtual void print() = 0;
                ^
```

**Note:** I know how to make it works, the B constructor will look like this:

```
  B(int a, int b): A(a,b) {}
```

But my real question is, what if I want to call the constructor of my derived class within the branches (like the above code)?
What is the correct way to call the abstract constructor within the branches?

Comment: So you want to call a contractor without actually contructing an object ? How come ? ... and more important, why ??

Comment: `A(a,b)` means construct a `A`, which is abstract so it fails.

Comment: "what if I want to call the constructor of my derived class within the branches" You meant call the constructor of `B` in the constructor of `B`?

Comment: You want call B construct in A ? That don't make sense. Where do you do that before ?

Comment: Suppose that I initialize necessary elements before calling A constructor.

Comment: Then, whatever code that you need in the constructor can be moved to another function ! you will not be able to construct object A anyways @KevinDelCastilloRamirez

Comment: @KevinDelCastilloRamirez I don't see why and no it's impossible.

Comment: Thanks you guys! I'm newbie, just asking if there is a way to do that, but I can't do that, so I learn something new today ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct way to call the abstract constructor within the branches?

There is none.

There is a very good reason for this. The superclass has to be constructed before your class can be constructed.

When you write the code for the constructor you have a reasonably constructed object. Your parent is constructed at the very least.

This is neatly expressed with the initialing syntax for the constructor.

```
B::B(int a, int b):A(a, b) {  
     // A is complete. now we can do stuff.
```

Answer (score 0):

you must initialize the part A of b in member-initializer list not inside the body of the B constructor:

```
class A
{
    virtual void print() = 0 {cout << "I am Pure function";}  
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B(int a, int b) : A(a,b) {}
        // B(int a, int b) {A(a,b);} /. incorrect
        void print()
      {
        cout << a << endl;
        cout << b << endl;
      }
};
```

- you can also define the pure virtual function to allow objects from derived class to chain up for functionality.